# file name "Car.java" this class is not compiling and showing error

Tags: java, interface, package

"Vehicle.java" this class is compiling and creating a package vehicles

```
package vehicles;
interface Vehicle {
    public void run();
    public void speed();
}
```

"Car.java"

```
package vehicles;
public class Car implements Vehicle
{
        public void run()
        {
                System.out.println("Car is running.");
        }
        public void speed()
        {
                System.out.println("Speed of Car: 50 Km/h");
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
                Car Car = new Car();
                Car.run();
                Car.speed();
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
}
```

is not compiling and showing error

```
PS D:\Programming\java2> javac -d . Car.java
Car.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
public class Car implements Vehicle
                            ^
symbol: class Vehicle
1 error
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Car.java and Vehicle.java reside in the same directory? Compile them both in one go.

If you want to compile them one by one, ensure that Vehicle.class is on the classpath while compiling Car.java.

Comment: how can i compile car.java after Vehicle.java  one by one using classpath

Comment: `PS D:\Programming\java2> javac vehicles\Car.java     `                                                                                            
`Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options`  **this is also not working**